# "Werktag" vs "Arbeitstag"

Tags: difference

I found this explanation here

https://www.lohnsteuer-kompakt.de/fag/0/703/was_ist_der_unterschied_zwischen_werktagen_und_arbeitstagen

But back on reverso

http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-german/workday

I can't quite see the difference explained. So, after all, how are *Werktag* and *Arbeitstag* different?

Comment: Nicht alle _Werktage_ sind auch _Arbeitstage_ (zum Glück).

Comment: Nicht alle *Arbeitstage* sind auch *Werktage* (leider).

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add the relevant quotes from your linked sources? Questions are supposed to stand for them selves.

Comment: Der Unterschied ist doch bei Quelle 1 erklärt. Sollen wir jetzt erklären, wieso Quelle 2 es nicht erklärt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first link gives the formality correct definitions:

- A **Werktag** is every day that’s *neither a Sonntag (Sunday) nor a Feiertag (public holiday)*.
- An **Arbeitstag** is a day when you go to work.

Always remember that we are looking at legal terms here, that are needed to clarify details in the context of employment and financial/tax laws. For the average 9-5 office workers, the difference is hardly noticeable in the day-to-day activities.
But the non-Werktage are especially protected by law - a company cannot simply have their employees work on Sundays. The exceptions need to be justified (think medical personnel, nuclear power plants, public transport...) and there’s typically some kind of compensation involved, extra time off or extra money.

So in the case of a hospital nurse, her Arbeitstage may include Sundays or Christmas, but they are still not Werktage.

The English language doesn’t use this distinction, this is why your reverso examples may seem confusing. In short, check the context and you should be fine following the distinction listed above.

Comment: The most important difference for most people is that Saturday is a *Werktag* but not an *Arbeitstag* (usually).

Comment: There are traffic signs (e.g. speed limits), which a restricted to *Werktags*, since it is pretty useless to refer to *Arbeitstag* here.

Comment: Das steht schon in seiner Quelle 1.

Comment: @userunknown ja, aber auf Deutsch. Was möglicherweise zusammen mit den Beispielen aus Quelle 2 unklar blieb.